# Is it possible to deploy the 'Start stop VM's during off-hours' solution of Automation account in ARM templates?

Tags: azure, automation, template, azure-arm-template

I need to deploy an Azure automation account to my resource group.
This to add the module ([start/stop VM's during off hours solution](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management) to my environment)
For the automation account I succesfully used the following [template](https://docs.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/templates/Microsoft.Automation/2015-10-31/automationAccounts). But to add the module I only found the gui solution through the portal.

The only way I found ATM is to create the module in the portal, find the runbooks that are begin created and create the exact same runbooks through an arm template with my Automation account template. But that doesn't seems to be very efficient.
Is there anyone who already deployed this in an ARM template or can help me guide me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/templates/Microsoft.Automation/2015-10-31/automationAccounts/modules

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that got here by searching the same thing as me i got a solution in this repo
https://github.com/Microsoft/MSITARM/tree/master/ARO-Toolkit-Marketplace

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 variables, 1 for the name of the module and 1 for the URI to the module
`"xDSCDomainjoin:1.1.0:Name": "xDSCDomainjoin",
"xDSCDomainjoin:1.1.0:Uri":"https://devopsgallerystorage.blob.core.windows.net/packages/xdscdomainjoin.1.1.0.nupkg"`

And then use this snippet of an ARM template, note the dependOn parameter which should point to you automation account.

```
{
"name": "[parameters('xDSCDomainjoin:1.1.0:Name')]",
"type": "modules",
"apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
"location": "[parameters('accountLocation')]",
"dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/', parameters('accountName'))]"
],
"tags": {},
"properties": {
    "contentLink": {
        "uri": "[parameters('xDSCDomainjoin:1.1.0:Uri')]"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is this module even do ?
i can't seem to find what the task is of the module ?

Comment: The module name and URI above is only an example, switch the variables with the modules that you want to use.